# Where can I find online playtesters to test encounters before presenting them to my group?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, encounter-design, online-roleplaying, playtesting, finding-other-players

I'm setting up the end of my campaign and I have 4 "mini-boss" fights (& Final BOSS fight) that I'm trying to make extremely tough but also winnable.  I don't want to just slaughter my PCs after all their hard work to get here but I also don't want to just spend the whole fight pulling my punches.

To solve this, I was hoping to find a place where I can get some "play testers" for these encounters.  I'm hoping to find a place where players are very knowledgeable on rules and strategies yet flexible enough to encompass house rules.

I have looked locally, but it seems most of the players local are into Pathfinder or 4E and it would be difficult to find players for a short time just to playtest.  So, although I've never played a tabletop online, I decided it could be a good place to look for playtesters.  Also, and more importantly, while I'm willing to play online for playtesting, its not something I want to run a continuing campaign on so it would be preferred if it was a place setup specifically for playtesters and not people looking for a new campaign.  Ideally, I would hope to find something that has an entire "section" of a forum or other online community.  I know that last part may be too specific and may not exist, so while it would be my ultimate goal I'd be happy to have something that will atleast let me accomplish my goals.

Does anyone know of any good place that fits what I'm looking for?

Side note:  I've never done ANY online play so I'd have to learn everything from the start..as in getting all my homemade maps/material online and learn to run them through it so hopefully it wouldn't be too difficult to learn.

Edit: I was trying to avoid PbP so I could get immediate feedback.  It wasn't clear in my original post.  I definitely looked for posts similar to this but didn't notice the one below during my search. Thx for the help everyone.

Comment: This is similar to (but perhaps different enough to not duplicate) [Finding online RPG players for a play-by-chat RPG Campaign?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/sites-for-finding-online-rpg-players-for-a-play-by-chat-rpg-campaign)

Comment: Duplicate of: [Is there any good place on the internet that hosts monster playtests?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/15699/4089)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you are looking for players. I suspect most players in an online one shot game won't care if they are doing the DM a service by playtesting something for the DMs regular group.

There are many online games played and organized on Google+ these days.

G+ RPG Hangouts: https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/101466247068767710475 is a good place to start.

In addition online virtual table tops like [Roll 20](http://roll20.net/) and [Map Tools](http://rptools.net/) all have communities where you could post for players

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the biggest/most currently active PbP (Play-by-Post) forums are

- [Giant in the Playground](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=3)
- [Paizo](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/community)

each maintains some sort of a community relating to the D&D 3.5 family.

Relevant for you, the GitP recruitment forum maintains a [guide](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=257924) for those who are new to PbP gaming, mentioning critical topics such as

- Game pacing
- Dealing with player dropouts (important!)
- Technical issues, such as dice rolling

Simon's answer links to tools such as Map Tools, which assist in such areas as uploading combat maps.