# How do I get my game reviewed?

Tags: publishing

I've created an RPG that's available free online as a Google doc, and want to get it some more exposure by having people write reviews of it. I tried finding reviewers on reddit/google+/twitter, but received little response. The project is non-profit, so paid reviews aren't an option.

How can I make it more likely for my game to be reviewed?

Comment: Welcome to RPG StackExchange! Feel free to [take the Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and if you have any questions take a look at the [Help Center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help). As per this question I have a feeling you need to state a bit more specifically what you want to achieve, so that the answers can be as precise as possible. As of now you might get a lot of answers and none of them would be "the right answer" - as per [this site's question format](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It looks like Pawel is asking for suggestions on where to ask that question, not asking for reviews here. I think it is a good question as is.

Comment: “How to X” is exactly the way we like questions like this to be asked. See [How do I find playtesters?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59808) for a similar question that's fine. I've edited this to be more purely a “how” question than a “recommend me sites” question, because it's quite possible that the best answer is not actually “try site XYZ” at all.

Comment: Those who have asked for a URL: we don't want to open the door to advertising that masquerades as a question. Answering this should require no knowledge of the actual game, as it's a problem applicable to any independently-produced RPG, so there's no practical need for our purposes anyway. [Meta discussion here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/why-cant-i-link-useful-but-non-critical-information-in-my-questions) on this subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Get a Wordpress site](https://wordpress.com/start/themes/en).  Publish your Google Doc as a PDF and post it for download there.  Now people can search for your site via Google, at least theoretically, and you can give them a URL that's human-readable.  All of the above is free, and you'll be [in good company](https://robboyle.wordpress.com/eclipse-phase-pdfs/).  An unsupported Google Doc is *not* a professional-looking distribution platform and is a red flag (to me at least).

Then **Host games yourself**, with strangers.  Start a game at your FLGS running one-shots and short campaigns, and try to expose the game to as many people as possible.  If your system is good, at least some of these people will be super excited about it, and hopefully run their own games with their private gaming groups.  This gets you at least *some* exposure, and makes it realistically possible for people who don't know each other to discuss your game. Once you've got the hang of GMing *short games* with the system and with complete strangers, exhibit the game at a local convention, preferably one held at your FLGS or which people from the FLGS will likely be attending.  Because you already have a small community of people interested in your game, your table should get a decent amount of traffic, which will make it very attractive to the kinds of people who write reviews of "up-and-coming" indie games.

Whenever you are wondering "Why aren't people doing X thing I want them to?" it's a good idea to think about what *they* get out of doing the thing.  I, and I imagine most people who at least occasionally write reviews, am fully aware that I cannot possibly write reviews for every RPG in existence, or even just every *new* RPG.  I don't get paid to write reviews, I write them because I want to share This Cool New Game (tm) with my friends and extended community and a review is a good way to let them know *why* it's cool, what I like about it, and how I want to play it, and to let them then decide if they think it's cool too.  This means that I only give reviews for games I have a reason to care about, and as the proponent of a 'random indie game' (this is what I will refer to you as in conversation, if I talk about you), the onus is entirely on you to give me an initial reason to care and, frankly, with the sheer amount of new, extremely similar, extremely low quality indie games floating around the internet, I won't even look at your game unless I see someone else (this person can be you) caring about it, or encounter it in person.

Like I said, I'm not a professional reviewer, and I also don't know any professional reviewers, so this is somewhat limited to those of us who write an rpg blog or something similar for fun/personal reasons, but I imagine as a professional reviewer having a reason to think my subject would be relevant to my audience would be even more important, not less.

Also, I'm old(fashioned), so this may be phasing out as the way reviewing is done, but I, at least, still pretty much exclusively write/share/care about systems I encounter in-person, not online (well, except email and the occasional awesome Q/A here).

Comment: You definitely hit the nail on the head with looking professional being the key. Putting it up on a Wordpress site is a huge step. Making it a PDF that looks nice is a big step too. And shelling out $12 or so for a domain name is the best if you are serious about promoting it. Things like this show that you have put effort into the game, and it isn't a half-baked RPG you came up with in an afternoon

Comment: As well as (or instead of) hosting on a WordPress site, you may want to put it on http://DrivethruRPG.com

Comment: @Adeptus No.  You really, really need a website.  Wordpress is ok.  Having DrivethuRPG is certainly an excellent *addition* but it can't really be standalone.